# Does Magick++ provide everything from the underlying API?

Tags: imagemagick, magick++, language-binding

Does Magick++ let you do everything that ImageMagick can do? A quick skim through the docs doesn't answer that question, and for example I couldn't find a Magick++ equivalent of [MagickSelectiveBlurImage](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickSelectiveBlurImage).

In case Magick++ is limited in that way, is it possible to e.g. use some methods from the C API to fill in the blanks? I.e. do the 2 APIs interoperate?

How about PythonMagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Magick++ API has likely not kept up with ImageMagick API changes.  The ImageMagick API is still available via a MagickLib namespace and if you study how the Magick++ Image class works, you will see that it is possible to use the C API and pass the result into Image.  It might be possible to inherit from Magick++ Image and add new methods that way.

PythonMagick is based on the Magick++ API so it supports what Magick++ does.

Bob Friesenhahn (Magick++ author)

Comment: Thanks, great to get a response from the author!

Comment: Note to other people: the namespace Bob mentioned seems to be called MagickCore and not MagickLib.